# Elliptic keyValueType ECDSAKeyValue

Tags: xades4j

We use Xades4j to validate signatures in xml files. This validation now fails because signatures contain a ecdsa:ECDSAKeyValue element

```
<ecdsa:ECDSAKeyValue xmlns:ecdsa="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#">
    <ecdsa:DomainParameters>
        <ecdsa:NamedCurve URN="urn:oid:1.3.36.3.3.2.8.1.1.7"/>
    </ecdsa:DomainParameters>
    <ecdsa:PublicKey>
        <ecdsa:X Value="18572964000475574191289519861917721795234288018618791443347147259050558052781" 
             xsi:type="ecdsa:PrimeFieldElemType"/>
        <ecdsa:Y Value="10002359033650864842631205094956892126968680447250207340443273037956040859507" 
             xsi:type="ecdsa:PrimeFieldElemType"/>
    </ecdsa:PublicKey>
</ecdsa:ECDSAKeyValue>
```

Does Xades4j support this type of KeyValue in signatures?

Answer (score 0):

Short answer is no.

xades4j relies on Apache Santuario for most of the XML-DSIG base processing. It seems that [only the JSR 105 bits support EC keys](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SANTUARIO-404). xades4j uses the `org.apache.xml.security` APIs mentioned on a comment on the issue, which still don't support EC keys.

As a side note, I'm not sure about the namespaces on your example. XML-DSIG 1.1 seems to [define different names/namespaces](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmldsig-core1/#sec-ECKeyValue). I think the URI on you example is actually [the signature algorithm identifier](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmldsig-core1/#sec-ECDSA).